# Bootstrap Media Queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the following code in my CSS stylesheet to target my jumbotron:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { 

    .jumbotron {
        padding-top: 500px !important;
        padding-bottom: 350px !important;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background: url(../images/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

}
```

The intent is just to increase the top and bottom padding of my jumbotron in mobile displays. But this code does not affect my jumbotron at all. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried using only `min-width` and only `max-width`, in addition to using both with the `and` as in the code above. All three have resulted in no changes.

Comment: Do you add this code in a `css` file or a `less` file? `@screen-sm-min` and `@screen-sm-max` are `less` vars, so you can't use them in `css`.

Comment: @media screen(min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max){}, and make sure it's a less / sass file since you're using vars which aren't supported by standard css

Comment: I am using CSS--I have not learned SASS/LESS--are there any attributes I can use to achieve the same result with CSS? Thank you for pointing that out, Seb33300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@screen-sm-min` and `@screen-sm-max` are less vars.
So you have to specify real values if you want to use them in CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
```

But if you want to apply a css style only on mobile devices, the correct media query should be:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
```

Comment: I replaced my `@media` tag with what you have here, and it also had no effect on my jumbotron.